# Aggregate a result set with node.js and mongodb in nested Array Structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query, grouping, aggregate-functions

after reading here for years and find good answers this is my first post on stackoverflow, because I'am facing a problem with node.js and mongodb.

I'am developing a polling system, with the following data structure.

#### mongodb Data Structure

```
{
    "_id" : "abcde",
    "course" : "FIAE17K",
    "poll" : "Poll1",
    "answers" : [ 
        {
            "question" : "Question1",
            "answer" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "question" : "Question2",
            "answer" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "question" : "Question3",
            "answer" : 1
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : "abcd",
    "course" : "FIAE17J",
    "poll" : "Poll1",
    "answers" : [ 
        {
            "question" : "Question1",
            "answer" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "question" : "Question2",
            "answer" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to make an evaluation of the Poll and may be would like to generate a JSON Structure like this... may be I need to do some transformations on the server side to get this format! The result array need to collect the number of answers for the specific question, eg. Question1 answered one time with 1 and one time with 3.

#### The 'perfect' Result Set

```
[
    {
        "titel": "Question1",
        "results": [1,0,1]
    },
    {
        "titel": "Question2",
        "results": [0,2]
    },
    {
        "titel": "Question3",
        "results": [1]
    }
]
```

As I understood correct I need to do an **aggregate function** with mongodb including a **$group** statement. But I don't know how, I start like the following...

```
db.antworten.aggregate([
    {$match: {"course":/FI/}},
    ?????
])
```

Comment: Why results are question 1 are [1,0,1] but not [1,3] ?

Comment: Because Question1 was answered 1 time with 1 and one time with 3. So the output was [1,0,1], but any other output that helps me to evaluate the poll would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've got closer to what i am looking for with this aggregate function:

```
db.anwers.aggregate([
    {$match: {"course":/FI/,"poll":"Poll1"}},
    {$unwind: "$answers"},
    {$group: {_id: "$answers",count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$sort: {_id: 1}}   
])
```

this produced

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "question" : "Question1",
        "answer" : 1
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "question" : "Question1",
        "answer" : 3
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "question" : "Question2",
        "answer" : 2
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "question" : "Question3",
        "answer" : 1
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

May be the rest I can do on the server side, or does any one find an other option so that I did'nt have to return all the questions redundant to the client side?